# Axler Theorem 3.47

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove Theorem 3.47 in Axler's book. The statement is:

> Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $C$ is an $n$-by-$p$ matrix. Then
> $$
> (AC)_{\cdot, k} = A C_{\cdot, k}. 
> $$

In Axler's notation, $(AC)_{\cdot, k}$ is notation for the $k$th column of $AC$ and $C_{\cdot, k}$ for the $k$th column of $C$. (Analogously, $C_{k, \cdot}$ is the $k$th row of $C$.)

I'm not sure how to prove this, though it's possible I'm just getting thrown off by the notation. Does it make sense to replace the $\cdot$ with a general $j$ (ranging from $1$ to $m$) and then conclude it's true for all $j$? Without this notation, I would prove this result by using the standard basis vectors. If $e_k$ is the $k$th standard basis vector, I'd say
$$
(AC)_{\cdot, k} = A(Ce_k) = A C_{\cdot ,k}.
$$
I'd appreciate some guidance on how to show this.

Comment: Your proof using standard basis vectors is already very good.

Answer (score 1):

To save space, I denote colums with transposed rows.

This is how the matrix $A$ is acting on the column $C_{.k}\,$:
$$
A C_{.k} = A\,(C_{1k}\,,\;C_{2k}\,,\;.\,.\,.\;C_{nk})^T
$$
$$
= \left(\sum_{r=1}^n A_{1r}C_{rk}  \;\;,\;\; \sum_{r=1}^n A_{2r}C_{rk}  \;\;,\;\;.\;.\;.\;\;,\;\; \sum_{r=1}^n A_{nr}C_{rk}\right)^T
\,\;,\;\;k=1,\,.\,.\,.\,p\;,\;\;\qquad(1)
$$
where the superscript $T$ indicates that in reality this is not a row but a column.

The product of $A$ and $C$ renders an $n\times p$ matrix whose $ij$ element is
$$
(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{r=1}^n A_{ir}C_{rj}\;.
$$
To find its $k$-th column, we fix $j=k$ and obtain, for the $i$-th element in that row:
$$
(AB)_{ik} = \sum_{r=1}^n A_{ir}C_{rk}\;.
$$
The entire row then looks as expression (1) above.